# Temperature and Humidity from Nest Protect

Tags: nest-api

The Nest Protect (smoke and CO alarm) can measure temperature and humidity but neither the official or unofficial API's appear to allow access to this data. Is anyone working on a work around? Any line of sight to accessing this data? Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
 $infos = (object) array(
        'current_state' => (object) array(
            'mode' => $mode,
            'temperature' => $this->temperatureInUserScale((float) $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->current_temperature),
            'humidity' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->current_humidity,
            'ac' => $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->hvac_ac_state,
            'heat' => $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->hvac_heater_state,
            'alt_heat' => $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->hvac_alt_heat_state,
            'fan' => $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->hvac_fan_state,
            'auto_away' => $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->auto_away, // -1 when disabled, 0 when enabled (thermostat can set auto-away), >0 when enabled and active (thermostat is currently in auto-away mode)
            'manual_away' => $manual_away,
            'leaf' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->leaf,
            'battery_level' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->battery_level
        ),
        'target' => (object) array(
            'mode' => $target_mode,
            'temperature' => $target_temperatures,
            'time_to_target' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->time_to_target,
```

Add this:

```
            'humidity' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->target_humidity, //added by Rick Ammazzini
            'humidity_enabled' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->target_humidity_enabled //added by Rick Ammazzini
        ),
        'serial_number' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->serial_number,
        'scale' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->temperature_scale,
        'location' => $structure,
        'line_power_present' => $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->line_power_present,
        'network' => $this->getDeviceNetworkInfo($serial_number),
        'name' => !empty($this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->name) ? $this->last_status->shared->{$serial_number}->name : DEVICE_WITH_NO_NAME,
        'where' => isset($this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->where_id) ? isset($this->where_map[$this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->where_id]) ? $this->where_map[$this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->where_id] : $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->where_id : ""
    );

    if($this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->has_humidifier) {
      $infos->current_state->humidifier= $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->humidifier_state;
      $infos->target->humidity = $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->target_humidity;
      $infos->target->humidity_enabled = $this->last_status->device->{$serial_number}->target_humidity_enabled;
    }
    return $infos;
}
```

Comment: Generally, it's poor practice to throw up poorly formatted code with a simple 'add this' in the middle. Why does this help? What is 'this'? Where should it be added?

Comment: Rick's code might be code for the Nest Thermostat, unfortunately not the Nest Protect.